# How to handle keyboard "Done" button in iphone safari browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, mobile-safari, keycode

I need to submit the form of a web page when the user pressed the "done" button on iPhone Safari browser. Does anybody know which Javascript event or keycode needs to use?

Comment: isn't just like an enter/return key?

Comment: Could you show your HTML?

Comment: Done should be the same as 'Enter'. See this response to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16740350/4636715

Comment: "Done" button simply hide the keyboard..

Comment: @vahdet: Tried, not working. Not only me more people response the same.