# Chrome mobile ios ckeditor done button not working

Tags: ios, google-chrome, ckeditor

I made many test on android with chrome, Firefox, ... also on iOS with chrome, Firefox, safari.
Chrome iOS is the only one to have the issue

https://jsfiddle.net/ajouve/vpq3zdr6/12/show

In CKEditor the done button of the virtual keyboard is not working, on click nothing happens, the keyboard is not going down

I tried with different versions of CKEditor I always have the same issue

This is my CKEditor instantiation

```
DecoupledEditor.create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
      toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'fontsize', 'fontfamily', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'highlight', '|', 'alignment', '|', 'numberedlist', 'bulletedlist', '|', 'undo', 'redo']
    })
    .then(theEditor => {
      const toolbarContainer = document.querySelector('#toolbar-container');
      editor = theEditor;
      toolbarContainer.appendChild(editor.ui.view.toolbar.element);

    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971061/capture-done-button-click-in-iphones-virtual-keyboard-with-javascript