Flutter web: TextField not unfocus when press on "Done" button from keyboard
There are 2 "Done" buttons when keyboard shows up:

When I press on the first Done button, keyboard hides, BUT the TextField still keeps the focusing status.
When I press on the second Done button, keyboard hides, and TextField also removes the focusing status.

Seems like the properties onSubmitted() and onEditingComplete() won't be triggered if I press on the first Done button.
Is there anyway to fix this issue? Or anyway to HIDE the first Done button? Thank you guys.

The source code is very simple:
void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter your name',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

You can edit the launch.json (if you use VSCode) configuration like this:
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "package_name", // package name
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "args": [
                "--release",
                "--web-hostname",
                "192.168.xxx.xxx", // your IP address
                "--web-port",
                "8080"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Then, you open your Safari from Simulator and open link: http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8080

Update (Nov 2024)
It is an issue from Flutter framework since v3.24: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/153616

It is the normal behavior of iOS. The first "done" button you're talking about is just a "hide my keyboard" button. It will not do anything else.
In Flutter you can try to add a "keyboardType" parameters:
TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.***,
          ),

I can't try on an iOS as I don't have one. But try different TextInputType, you may be able to remove this done button.
More info :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75842595/9990911
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputType-class.html

i tried to change keyboardType, but no help. The first "Done" button still shows up. I just found a GitHub issue here. They still opening it. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/153616

Oh, so Flutter 3.24 starts to happen this bug

you can use Specific FocusNode for the TextField and then after pressing the done button that FocusNode variable set to unfocus.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
